# PDF to print iteration in PHP

Tags: php, xml, pdf, simplexml

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to iterate over an array of SimpleXML objects that contain PDF data and have each print to separate PDF files? I've been fighting with this for over a week now. My latest loop code is as follows:

```
foreach($xml->DocumentPDFs->DocumentPDF->PDFBytes as $PDFBytes => $value) {
    $binary = base64_decode($value);
    file_put_contents($xml->EnvelopeStatus->EnvelopeID . "/" . $xml->EnvelopeStatus->DocumentStatuses->DocumentStatus->Name . ".pdf", $binary,FILE_APPEND);
}
```

This prints out the first PDF and then exits the loop.

Comment: Yes its possible, I don't know if the way your doing it is the way though. sounds like your loop is being broken by something in the print object.

Comment: Are you talking about my file_put_contents?

Comment: yes, it could be, really need more detail, are you displaying PHP errors if not do you have error catching enabled?

Comment: I have `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` enabled in my script. It shows nothing.

Comment: hmmm try seeing if the loop itself will run through the files without printing to pdf, make them echo foo bar on each iteration and see if it does all of them, that will narrow it down.

Comment: I've already tried that and it prints all to the screen.

Comment: So I have this: `foreach($xml->DocumentPDFs->DocumentPDF as $value) { $valuename = $value->Name; print("<pre>".print_r($valuename,true)."</pre>"); $output = print_r($valuename, true); file_put_contents($docname . ".txt", $output); }`. It prints this to the screen: `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Corporate_Information ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => LLC_Information )`. It writes a file called the name of the first PDF with the title of the second PDF in it. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was syntax issues. Both in the base64_decode call and the file_put_contents call:

```
foreach($xml->DocumentPDFs->DocumentPDF as $value) {
    $binary = base64_decode($value->PDFBytes);
    file_put_contents($xml->EnvelopeStatus->EnvelopeID . "/" . $value->Name . ".pdf", $binary);
}
```

So there you go.